# I want to send a message to all my winxp clients from my win xp workstation

Tags: windows-xp

I need to communicate eache client seperatly by send alerts or warnings on required basis . I am working in WINXP environment. I need send a message from winxp client workstation to all. I tried to use net send but here as per security policy the messanger service is desabled . so help me pout is there any way to send a message to all cliens.

Answer (score 1):

You will need something to send messages to if you don't want to use the Messenger service. If you google "Desktop Alert Software" you will find a lot of 3rd party solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not get the service activated instead so you can use NET SEND?

Comment: From what I understand, the Messenger Service can be used by spammers to send messages directly to your desktop.  This was the case with Win2000 anyway.  I assume thats why its disabled by default now.

Comment: :-) It was a rhetorical sort of question cop1152.

I was hinting that the messenger service was probably left disabled by the admin, to avoid what the original poster is probably trying to do on this network - sending unsolicited messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Microsoft Office Communications Server](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicationsserver/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Run a script using pstools to reable the messenger service then use netsend, then have your script turn the service back off.

Download pstools from sysinternals
Download EZ-execute from penguin bytes

Make 3 batch files
  psservice \%computername% start messenger
  net send * Hello World
  psservice \%computername% stop messenger

Use EZ-Execute to run the 1st script against the domain
Use the 2nd script to send the message to the domain
Use EZ-Execute to run the 3rd script against the domain

You could also put this all into one script using psexec if you are going to do this on a regular basis.

http://ss64.com/nt/psservice.html
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-u/net_send.mspx?mfr=true